# Javascript regex to search string between {}

Tags: javascript, regex

I have below URL, I need to extract the word present between flower brackets "Control1_Value" & "Control2_Value". I am new to regex please help me in getting the regex solved.

```
   <http://localhost:85/Default.aspx?FormName=Default&StartTime=Now-1month&EndTime=Now&Action=Edit&ControlName=Control1&ControlValue={Control1_Value}& ControlName=Control2&ControlValue={Control2_Value}#/SampleApp>
```

Few options I tried but in vain, below is the regex I tried but could not get exactly what I needed.

This is the regex I tried: `/\{(.*)|_|Value\}/`

Output of the above regex returned:

```
{Control1_Value}& ControlName=Control2&ControlValue={Control2_Value}#/SampleApp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\{([^\}]*)\}
```

You can simply use this or

```
\{(.*?)\}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the regex

```
var regex = /[^{]+?(?=})/g;
'<http://localhost:85/Default.aspx?FormName=Default&StartTime=Now-1month&EndTime=Now&Action=Edit&ControlName=Control1&ControlValue={Control1_Value}& ControlName=Control2&ControlValue={Control2_Value}#/SampleApp>'.match(regex );
```

Demo: [RegEx](http://regexr.com/3b134)